# how to parse json data content?

Tags: python, json, loops, dictionary, parsing

being new to python I have the following I would like to achieve:
My json input looks like something as follows:

```
{
"organisaties": [
    {
        "oin": "00000001855432950000",
        "naam": "ABG - organisatie",
        "status": "Actief",
        "kvkNummer": "63865718",
        "organisatieCode": null,
        "organisatieType": null,
        "afgifteDatum": "2016-05-22T22:00:00Z",
        "laatstAangepastDatum": "2018-05-07T22:00:00Z",
        "intrekDatum": null
    },
    {
        "oin": "00000004145716135000",
        "naam": "ActiecentrumVeiligheid en Zorg",
        "status": "Actief",
        "kvkNummer": null,
        "organisatieCode": null,
        "organisatieType": null,
        "afgifteDatum": "2019-09-16T09:45:49Z",
        "laatstAangepastDatum": "2019-09-19T09:46:14Z",
        "intrekDatum": null,
        "hoofdOIN": {
            "id": "https://portaal.digikoppeling.nl/registers/api/v1/organisaties/00000001825783434000"
        }
    },
    {
        "oin": "00000004000000140000",
        "naam": "Agentschap SZW",
        "status": "Ingetrokken",
        "kvkNummer": null,
```

.
.

I can read this from a file and from the internet I learned of the possibility to load this json formatted text into a dict.  with the following snippet

`inputfile_object = open('organisaties_all.txt', 'r')
    x = inputfile_object.read()
    y = json.loads(x)`

y is then a dict with one(1) key "organisaties" and y.values() dumps the entire subsection of 1161 records (each starting with the "oin" field in this case.

Furthermore I can print sub contents of individual records like so

`print (y["organisaties"][200]["oin"])`

However I want to iterate through all the individual elements and extract field contents thereof. 
I fail to see currently how to do that

Please advice for this scenario on how to accomplish this or if there are better approaches please let me know

Thanks

Peter

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate like this, IIUC:

```
for items in f['organisaties']: 
    print(items['oin'])
```

Answer (score 0):

I give you 2 options for parse your json file :

```
import json
with open('test1.json', 'rt') as f:
  data = json.load(f)

# Option 1 with a loop
for x in data['organisaties']:
    print(x['oin'])

# Option 2 using pandas
# pip install pandas (for install the library)
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data['organisaties'])
print(df['oin'])
# With pandas is more easy to convert the information to to_csv
df.to_csv('test1.csv',index=False)
```